# Reordering using Patterns in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, design-patterns

Trying to do this :

```
list={{{33, 105, 203, 295}, {34, 106, 204, 296}}, 
      {{21, 135, 201, 333}, {22,136, 202, 334}}}
```

I would like to transform sublists so that the first one:

{{33, 105, 203, 295}, {34, 106, 204, 296}}

becomes

{{33, 204, 106, 295}, {34, 106, 105, 296}}

I don`t understand what I am doing wrong in the following :

```
list /. {{a_,b_,c_,d_}, {e_,f_,g_,h_}} :> 
        {{a_,g_,f_,d_}, {e_,c_,b_,h_}}
```

EDIT

Thanks to Leonid`s Comment, the below now works

```
 list /. {{a_,b_,c_,d_}, {e_,f_,g_,h_}} :> 
         {{a,g,f,d}, {e,c,b,h}}
```

If somebody knows a better way to do this, don`t hesitate.

Comment: Just remove the blanks on the r.h.s. of your rule: `a` instead of `a_` etc. Blanks are normally only used on the l.h.s. of the rule, and pattern variables are used on the r.h.s. Is your total list large?

Comment: @Leonid, I actually don`t have the blank in my code but it still does not work. Total list is only 48 such sublist. Thank You

Comment: I meant not the blank spaces, but the underscore characters `_`. Your rule should be `{{a_,b_,c_,d_}, {e_,f_,g_,h_}} :> {{a,g,f,d}, {e,c,b,h}}`.

Comment: You want to write that as a solution :-) ?

Comment: No time right now to generalize it so that it is more generally useful. Unless someone else takes it up, will do tomorrow.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As Leonid wrote, but declined to post as an answer, your pattern works once it is corrected:

```
list /. {{a_,b_,c_,d_}, {e_,f_,g_,h_}} :> {{a, g, f, d}, {e, c, b, h}}
```

This is the most direct way to accomplish this task, but as Leonid also wrote, it is not the most general.  Here is another way, admittedly without patterns, that you might approach this:

```
orderBy[list_, order_] := Partition[Flatten[#][[order]], 4] & /@ list

orderBy[list, {1, 7, 6, 4, 5, 3, 2, 8}]
```

This allows you to specify the reordering as a simple permuation, easily written by hand, or generated with `RandomeSample@Range@8`.

If your data has more variety of shape, this can be extended with different `Partition` parameters, etc.

Comment: @500 I changed `orderBy` slightly, making it significantly more efficient.